# Removing a row from CSV with python if data wasn't recorded in a column

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to import a batch of CSV's into PostgreSQL and constantly run into an issue with missing data:

> psycopg2.DataError: missing data for column "column_name" CONTEXT:
>   COPY table_name, line *where ever in the CSV that data wasn't
>
>   recorded, and here are data values up to the missing column*.

There is no way to get the complete set of data written to the row at times, and I have to deal with the files as is. I am trying to figure a way to remove the row if data wasn't recorded into any column. Here's what I have:

```
file_list = glob.glob(path)

for f in file_list:
    filename = os.path.basename(f) #get the file name
    arc_csv = arc_path + filename #path for revised copy of CSV

    with open(f, 'r') as inp, open(arc_csv, 'wb') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out)
        for line in csv.reader(inp):
            if "" not in line: #if the row doesn't have any empty fields
                writer.writerow(line)

    cursor.execute("COPY table_name FROM %s WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','",(arc_csv,))
```

Comment: Since I have a rep of less than 15 my post score for the responses wont show. Thanks cant and alecxe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pandas to remove rows with missing values:

```
import glob, os, pandas

file_list = glob.glob(path)

for f in file_list:
    filename = os.path.basename(f)
    arc_csv = arc_path + filename
    data = pandas.read_csv(f, index_col=0)
    ind = data.apply(lambda x: not pandas.isnull(x.values).any(), axis=1)
    # ^ provides an index of all rows with no missing data
    data[ind].to_csv(arc_csv) # writes the revised data to csv
```

However, this could get slow if you're working with large datasets.

EDIT - added `index_col=0` as an argument to `pandas.read_csv()` to prevent the added index column issue. This uses the first column in the csv as an existing index. Replace 0 with another column's number if you have reason not to use the first column as index.

Comment: Thanks! Seems just about right, except it creates a new column (column A) with the rows numbered (0 - last row #). Reading more on pandas now.

Comment: My bad, edited my post to prevent the additional column issue. Pandas dataframes require an index so if it isn't specified a new one is generated.

Comment: Thanks again. I bearly gotten into reading on pandas and here you are in no time with an answer! I'm also reading up on the issue that alecxe brought to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you *cannot parameterize table or column names*. Use string formatting, but make sure to validate/escape the value properly:

```
cursor.execute("COPY table_name FROM {column_name} WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','".format(column_name=arc_csv))
```